# Static method call in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, styles, microsoft-metro

How can I use static method (with parameter) in xaml in metro style app? In wpf I could use  **ObjectDataProvider** but there is no such a thing in WinRT.

I need use it sth like this:

```
<button x:Name="MyButton" Content=MyStaticMethodCall("Sth") />
```

Is there a way to do this? Or store object in resource and then call his method sth like this?

```
<button x:Name="MyButton" Content={StaticResource MyObject, Path=MyObject.MyMethod("bla") />
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember in a previous project that in metro apps was not possible to access static code. We had to reference some constant and there was no way to reference them if they were const or static. But time passed maybe something changed but i doubt it...

Comment: no sorry at the end for constant we just duplicated the definition in the xaml page... but for function i really don't know

Answer (score 0):

I´m not sure about what you want, but why don´t use MarkupExtension.

You can simply add in xaml and then use the ProvideValue method to invoke the static method.

Just leave a comment if you need a code example.

Comment: It would be nice. But I don't think it'd solve my problem. I need to get the result of method and set for example Content property of button. I think I'd be able to take the "sender" object, but not every object has Content - Let's say I want to set Text property. Then I need to use casting or reflection to get properties names. Other way is to pass the property name that method's result should be assigned to. Maybe it's ugly but if there wouldn't be alternatives..

Comment: WinRT doesn't provide MarkupExtension.

Comment: What a pitty. What about using a value converter? They do not need to derive from MarkupExtension to be instantiated in XAML. You can also provide the control which is attached and of course the converter parameter. Try something like Converter={mynamespace:MyConverter Property1 = "Hello World", Property2 = {StaticResource resourceKey}}

Comment: That could be a not bad idea. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how it works, instead of calling a method you should use DataBinding - set the DataContext of Button or the whole page to your object and then bind the Button Content like this:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="{Binding ButtonContent}" />
```

Some basic info about DataBinding is here:
[A Guided Tour of WPF – Part 3 (Data binding)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18270/A-Guided-Tour-of-WPF-Part-3-Data-binding)

Comment: No, I can't set DataContext. I want to bind method, because content depends on a parameter. I'm not able to create all content scenarios and put them as properites of DataContext.

Comment: Since you cannot bind to methods, you could use Converter and ConverterParameter in your binding and in there return whatever you want.